# Kotlin coroutines in CoroutineWorker

Tags: multithreading, android-workmanager, kotlin-coroutines

I am using CoroutineWorker to take some data from room db and post it to server then again delete that particular answer from db. I am using repository pattern.

```
class SendLocalAnswerToServer(ctx: Context, val params: WorkerParameters) :
    CoroutineWorker(ctx, params) {

var useCaseHandler: UseCaseHandler? = null
var deleteAnswerFromTable: DeleteAnswerFromTable? = null
private var uploadAutoSavedAnswer: UploadAutoSavedAnswer? = null
val TAG:String= "SendLocalAnswerToServer"

override suspend fun doWork(): Result = runBlocking {
    val questionID = params.inputData.getLong("questionID", 0)
    val answerDao = UserDatabase.getDatabase(App.getInstance()).answerDao()
    val answerAPIRepo = NetWorkUtil.provideRetrofit().create(AnswerAPI::class.java)
    uploadAutoSavedAnswer = UploadAutoSavedAnswer(this, answerDao, answerAPIRepo)
    deleteAnswerFromTable = DeleteAnswerFromTable(this, answerDao)
    useCaseHandler = InjectionUtils.provideUseCaseHandler()
    val requestValues = UploadAutoSavedAnswer.RequestValues()
    requestValues.questionID = questionID
    Log.e(TAG, " Main 1")

    launch {
        useCaseHandler!!.execute(uploadAutoSavedAnswer!!, requestValues,
                object :
                        UseCase.UseCaseCallback<UploadAutoSavedAnswer.ResponseValues> {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: UploadAutoSavedAnswer.ResponseValues) {
                                Log.e(TAG, " onSuccess 1")
                                response.observable?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.observeOn(
                                        AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())!!.subscribeWith(

                                        object :
                                                DisposableObserver<UserAnswerResponseModel>() {
                                            override fun onComplete() {
                                            }

                                            override fun onNext(t: UserAnswerResponseModel) {

                                                Log.e("TAG", " onNext ")
                                                val requestValues = DeleteAnswerFromTable.RequestValues()
                                                requestValues.answerID = t.question.id!!
                                                useCaseHandler?.execute(
                                                        deleteAnswerFromTable!!,
                                                        requestValues,
                                                        object :
                                                                UseCase.UseCaseCallback<DeleteAnswerFromTable.ResponseValues> {
                                                            override fun onSuccess(
                                                                    response: DeleteAnswerFromTable.ResponseValues) {
                                                                Log.e("TAG", " onSuccess 2")
                             // I want to return Result.Success() from here
                                                            }

                                                            override fun onError(
                                                                    throwable: Throwable) {
                            // I want to return Result.Error() from here
                                                            }
                                                        })
                                            }

                                            override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                                            }
                                        })


                    }

                    override fun onError(throwable: Throwable) {
                    }
                })
    }
    Log.e(TAG, " MAIN 2")
    Result.success()

}
}
```

The output prints

```
E/SendLocalAnswerToServer:  Main 1
E/SendLocalAnswerToServer:  MAIN 2
```

How can I return value from last success or return method, right now it goes into first function **useCaseHandler!!.execute()** which further starts a new thread so coroutines just returns from there any solution such that when the whole api call and further deletion from table has been done then only it should return success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `useCaseHandler.execute(...)` which thread does it execute the request on? The problem is that you are actually not using coroutines at all. You are mixing a callbacks based API and an Rx based API (incorrectly).

You have 2 options. Either use coroutines correctly or use a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: it is mix of both useCaseHandler.execute(...) starts a new thread because and then i have defines different coroutines to query the db and then post the data obtained from db to server using RxJava, so its a mix of both , can you provide me more insight how to restructure it. Initially I was using countdown and launch but when both combines the inner methods were not getting called, but after removing launch it worked, thanks for that.